# NoSuchMethodError when requesting an Authenticated action in a test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

There is an action which i want to unit test.

```
def foo = AuthenticatedAction(BodyParsers.parse.json){...}
```

The problem is that the unit test throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: pdi.jwt.package$.RichRequestHeader(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;)Lpdi/jwt/JwtPlayImplicits$RichRequestHeader;
```

When i use `Action` instead of `AutenticatedAction` the tests are doing well and thats were google & co can not really provide help. Also the play docs are not helpful.

How can I test such an action?

Thats the testing request:

```
val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/foo").withHeaders(("Authorization",jwttoken)).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(content)))
```

P.S. The exception is thrown when I call `contentAsString` on the result object.